# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^6+1}\,dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand how to evaluate the following integral.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^6+1}dx$$

We start by considering $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z^6+1}dz.$ Then we find that $z_k = \exp \left (i \left (\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi k}{3}\right)\right )$, and simple poles occur when $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Then

$$\text{Res}(f,z_k)= \dots =\dfrac{1}{6}\lim_{z \to z_k} z^{-5}= \dfrac{1}{6} \exp \left( -\frac{5 \pi i}{6} (1 +2k) \right)$$

I think that in the missing part, the following formula is used,

$$\text{Res}(f,c)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} ((z-c)^n f(z)) $$

that $n=4$ and that a cancellation occurs (otherwise it would be really messy), but I'm not sure how to do it. How do I proceed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is rather peculiar: the denominator factors to
$$ \prod_{k=0}^5 (z-z_k), $$
and the function has no real roots, so you take the three in the upper half-plane and find the residues at their poles. The three roots are simple, so the residue formula in its most basic form should be used, and you find something like
$$ 2\pi i \left( \prod_{k=1}^5 \frac{1}{z_0-z_k} + \prod_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \neq 1}}^5 \frac{1}{z_1-z_k} + \prod_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \neq 2}}^5 \frac{1}{z_2-z_k} \right). $$
But as far as I know, there is no simpler way of doing this: you can make various simplifications, but you still end up having to push quite a lot of algebra through.

---

However, you don't need to do it that way: first, the integrand is symmetric, so the integral is twice the integral over $[0,\infty)$. Now substitute $x=y^{1/6}$, so
$$ I = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{6} \frac{y^{-5/6}}{1+y} \, dy $$
There are a variety of ways of doing this integral, probably the easiest being to substitute $u=y/(1+y)$. Then $y= u/(1-u)= 1+\frac{1}{u-1}$, $dy = \frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \, du $, so
$$ I = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{u}{1-u} \right)^{-5/6} \frac{1-u}{1-u+u} \frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \, du = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 u^{-5/6} (1-u)^{-1/6} \, du = \frac{1}{3}\frac{\Gamma(1/6)\Gamma(5/6)}{\Gamma(1)} = \tfrac{1}{3}\pi\csc{\tfrac{1}{6}\pi}, $$
using the Beta function.

Comment: Nice. I generalized your second proof to $n > 1$.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to generalize
Chappers's nice result
and see if I get anywhere.

Let
$J_n
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^n+1}dx
$,
where
$n > 1$.
Note that this is
half of the integral from
$-\infty$ for even $n$,
but is nicer to work with.

Let $x = y^{1/n}$,
so
$dx = \frac1{n}y^{1/n-1}dy$.
Then
$J_n
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{n} \dfrac{y^{1/n-1}dy}{y+1}
$.

As was done,
let
$u=\frac{y}{1+y}$
so
$y = \frac{u}{1-u}$.
Then
$dy = \frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \, du$
so

$\begin{array}\\
J_n
&=\frac1{n}\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)^{1/n-1}du}{(1-u)^2(1+u/(1-u))}\\
&=\frac1{n}\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{u^{1/n-1}(1-u)^{1-1/n}du}{(1-u)(1-u+u)}\\
&=\frac1{n}\int_{0}^{1} u^{1/n-1}(1-u)^{-1/n}du\\
&=\frac1{n}B(1/n, -1/n+1) \quad\text{(the Beta function)}\\
&=\dfrac{\Gamma(1/n)\Gamma(-1/n+1)}{n\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\Gamma(1/n)\Gamma(-1/n+1)\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/n)}\quad\text{(reflection formula)}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi\csc(\pi/n)}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

and it works out fine.

Note that I did almost nothing
original here -
I replaced $6$ with $n$
and followed
Chappers's script.

Comment: I can do you one better: I proved an even more general case here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231316/difficult-improper-integral-int-0-infty-fracx235x27217-mat/1231353#1231353

Comment: Very nice. Upvoted. Though in equation (1) you left off the "dx".

Comment: Goodness, how embarrassing... fixed.

Comment: The demon proofreader strikes again.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to help with the algebra which needn't be difficult. 
Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2m}} dx$$
which does not have a pole on the real axis at $x=-1.$

I think the  approach of using the residues of the  poles in the upper
half  plane is  not  necessarily  the best  here,  for an  alternative
consult                 e.g.                 this                 [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973801/).

Note that the poles at 
$\rho_k = \exp(\frac{\pi i}{2m} + \frac{\pi i k}{m})$
are simple and hence the residues are given by

$$\left.\frac{1}{(x^{2m}+1)'}\right|_{x=\rho_k}
= \left.\frac{1}{2mx^{2m-1}}\right|_{x=\rho_k}
= \left.\frac{x}{2mx^{2m}}\right|_{x=\rho_k}
= -\frac{1}{2m}\rho_k.$$

Therefore we get for the sum of the residues
$$-\frac{1}{2m} \exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{2m}\right)
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \exp\left(\frac{\pi i k}{m}\right)
= -\frac{1}{2m} \exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{2m}\right)
\frac{\exp(\pi i m/m)-1}{\exp(\pi i/m)-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{m} \exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{2m}\right)
\frac{1}{\exp(\pi i/m)-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{m} 
\frac{1}{\exp(\pi i/2/m)-\exp(-\pi i/2/m)}
\\ = \frac{1}{m\times 2i} \frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2/m)}.$$

This yields for the integral
$$2\pi i \times 
\frac{1}{m\times 2i} \frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2/m)}
= \frac{1}{m} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/2/m)}.$$

Comment: What if m is not an integer? My/Chapper's proof does not require this.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to consider the pole at $\exp(i\pi/6)$, because you can consider the contour from $0$ to $R$, from $R$ to $R\exp(i \pi/3)$ and then back to $0$ along the line $z = r\exp(i \pi/3)$ where $r$ goes from $R$ to $0$. In the limit of $R$ to infinity, the contour integral becomes:

$$I_c = \left[1-\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{3}\right)\right] \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^6+1} $$

The residue theorem yields:

$$I_c = 2\pi i\lim_{z\to\exp\left(i\pi/6\right)}\frac{z-\exp\left(\frac{i \pi}{6}\right)}{z^6+1} = \frac{i\pi}{3}\exp\left(-\frac{5i \pi}{6}\right)$$

Therefore

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^6+1} =\frac{\pi}{3\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}=\frac{2\pi}{3} $$

Comment: This approach is used at the [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973801/) that I included below.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Yes, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

We first resolve the integrand into partial fractions.
$$
\frac{1}{x^{6}+1}=\frac{1}{3\left(x^{2}+1\right)}-\frac{x^{2}-2}{3\left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)}
$$

Integrating both sides yields

$$
3 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{6}+1}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{2}+1}-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}-2}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1} d x
$$
Obviously,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{2}+1}=\left[\tan ^{-1} x\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2} 
$$
Now let’s deal with the latter one.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}-2}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1} d x = &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\frac{2}{x^{2}}}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1} d x
\\=& \frac{3}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) d x}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1}-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) d x}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1} \\
=& \frac{3}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}-3}-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+1} \\
=& \frac{\sqrt3}{4}\left[\ln \left|\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt3}{x+\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt3}\right|\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
=&-\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
3 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{6}+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi
$$

Now we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{6}+1}=\frac{2 \pi}{3}}
$$